# Why would you recursively define macros in terms of other macros in C?

Tags: c, arduino

I wanted to see how the arduino function `digitalWrite` actually worked. But when I looked for the source for the function it was full of macros that were themselves defined in terms of other macros. Why would it be built this way instead of just using a function? Is this just poor coding style or the proper way of doing things in C?

For example, `digitalWrite` contains the macro `digitalPinToPort`.

```
#define digitalPinToPort(P) ( pgm_read_byte( digital_pin_to_port_PGM + (P) ) )
```

And `pgm_read_byte` is a macro:

```
#define pgm_read_byte(address_short)    pgm_read_byte_near(address_short)
```

And `pgm_read_byte_near` is a macro:

```
#define pgm_read_byte_near(address_short) __LPM((uint16_t)(address_short))
```

And `__LPM` is a macro:

```
#define __LPM(addr)         __LPM_classic__(addr)
```

And `__LPM_classic__` is a macro:

```
#define __LPM_classic__(addr)   \
(__extension__({                \
    uint16_t __addr16 = (uint16_t)(addr); \
    uint8_t __result;           \
    __asm__ __volatile__        \
    (                           \
        "lpm" "\n\t"            \
        "mov %0, r0" "\n\t"     \
        : "=r" (__result)       \
        : "z" (__addr16)        \
        : "r0"                  \
    );                          \
    __result;                   \
}))
```

Not directly related to this, but I was also under the impression that double underscore should only be used by the compiler. Is having `LPM` prefixed with `__` proper?

Comment: "When your only hammer is C, everything starts to look like your thumb."

Comment: The code you describe does seem to be unusually dense with macros, but your question is substantially one of general coding style, which is primarily a matter of opinion.  As such, the question is inappropriate for SO, and I have voted to close it.

Comment: @JohnBollinger on which board would it be appropriate for Legion to ask what motivations and coding philosophy is behind this *style*?

Comment: @PatrickTrentin, the particular question is not suited for Code Review SE, but questions there often do elicit answers discussing code style to a greater or lesser extent.  And perhaps a question along these lines would be well received at Software Engineering SE.  In any event, whether either of those, or even some other site, is an appropriate venue for the question has no bearing on whether it is appropriate for *this* venue.

Comment: You can use eclipse to fully unwind the macros that arduino uses... In fact, there is this plugin (http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/Eclipse) that allow you to do exactly that... just hover with your keyboard above digitalWrite and it will pop up a window with the macros fully expanded.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I wasn't questioning your judgment, I agree on that, I just wanted to give Legion the right direction on where to go to post this question because I am interested in the answer. And I thought you would know better than me where to send him. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your question is "why one would use multiple layers of macros?", then:

- why not? Notably in the pre-C99 era without `inline`. A canonical example was 1980s era `getc` which was (IIRC) at that time (SunOS3.2, 1987) *documented* as being a macro, with a *NOTE* in the `man` page telling  (I forgot the details) that with some `FILE* filearr[];` a `getc(filearr[i++])` was wrong (IIRC, the *undefined behavior* terminology did not exist at that time). When you looked into some system headers (e.g. `<stdio.h>` or some header included by it) you could find the definition of such macro. And *at that time* (with computers running *only* at a few MHz, so thousand times slower than today) `getc` *has to* be a macro for efficiency reasons (since `inline` did not exist, and compilers did no [interprocedural optimizations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interprocedural_optimization) like they are able to do now). Of course, you could use `getc` in *your own* macros.
- even today, some standards define macros. In particular today's [waitpid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html) system call document `WIFEXITED` & `WEXITSTATUS` as macros, and it is sensible to `#define` some of your macros mixing both of them.
- the main point is to understand the working of the [C preprocessor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor), and its profoundly textual (so very *brittle*) nature. This is explained in all textbooks about C. Hence you need to understand what is happening under the hoods.
- the rule of thumb with modern era C (that is C99 & C11) is to systematically prefer having some `static inline` function (defined in some header file) to an equivalent macro. In other words, `#define` some macro only when you cannot avoid it. And explicitly document that fact.
- several layers of macro might (sometimes) increase code readability.
- macros can be tested with `#ifdef macroname` which is sometimes useful.

Of course, when you dare defining several layers of macros (I won't call them "recursive", read about [self-referential macros](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Self-Referential-Macros.html)) you need to be very careful and understand what is happening with all of them (combined & separately). Looking into the preprocessed form is helpful.

BTW, to debug complex macros, I sometimes do

```
gcc -C -E -I/some/directory mysource.c | sed 's:^#://#:' > mysource.i
```

then I look into the `mysource.i` and sometimes even have to compile it, perhaps as `gcc -c -Wall mysource.i` to get warnings which are located in the *preprocessed* form `mysource.i` (which I can examine in my `emacs` editor). The `sed` command is "commenting" the lines starting with `#`  which are setting source location (à la `#line`).... Sometimes I even do `indent mysource.i`

(actually, I have a special rule for that in my `Makefile`)

> Is having LPM prefixed with __ proper?

BTW, names starting with `_` are (by the standard, and conventionally) reserved to the implementation. In principle you are not allowed to have your names starting with `_` so there cannot be any collision.

Notice that the `__LPM_classic__` macro uses the [statement-expr extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html)
(of [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) & [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/))

Look also at other programming languages. Common Lisp has a very different model of macros (and a much more interesting one). Read about [hygienic macros](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hygienic_macro). My personal regret is that the C preprocessor has never evolved to be much more powerful (and Scheme-like). Why that did not happen (imagine a C preprocessor able to invoke [Guile](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/) code to do the macro expansion!) is probably for sociological & economical reasons.

You still should *sometimes* consider using some other preprocessor (like [m4](https://www.gnu.org/software/m4/m4.html) or [GPP](https://logological.org/gpp)) to *generate* C code. See [autoconf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoconf).

Answer (score 4):

> Why would it be built this way instead of just using a function?

The purpose is likely to optimize functions' calls using pre-C99 compilers, that don't support inline functions (via `inline` keyword). This way, the whole stack of function-like macros is essentially merged by preprocessor into single block of code.

Every time you call a function in C, there is a tiny overhead, because of jumping around program's code, managing the stack frame and passing arguments. This cost is negligible in most applications, but if the function is called very often, then it may become a performance bottleneck.

> Is this just poor coding style or the proper way of doing things in C?

It's hard to give definitive answer, because coding style is subjective topic. I would say, consider using inline functions or even (better) let the compiler inline them by itself. They are type-safe, more readable, more predictable, and with the proper assistance from compiler, the net result is essentially the same.

Related reference (it's for C++, but the idea is generally the same for C):

- [Why should I use inline functions instead of plain old #define macros?](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/inline-functions#inline-vs-macros)

Comment: This speaks to one reason for using macros in general, but it doesn't address the OP's primary concern, which pertains to using multiple layers of macros.

Comment: Another reason could be, since there are many different AVR micro controller types, macro's are used so the correct implementation for some operation can be chosen based on device type at compile time, or at least leave this option open for the future.